# Gastronomic and Gastronomical

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, difference

Gastronomic and gastronomical both are adjectives and I want to know if these two can supplant each other. Majority of the dictionaries mention these words as synonyms. If there is a difference between them can somebody explain it in a simple way?

Some of the example sentences:

1. **Lyon is the gastronomic capital of France and the gold standard for chefs around the world.**
2. **Lyon is the gastronomical capital of France and the gold standard for chefs around the world.**
3. **the hotel restaurant serves the most exclusive gastronomic delights.**
4. **the hotel restaurant serves the most exclusive gastronomical delights.**

Are all these sentences correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the two terms can be used interchangeably, gastronomic being the more common one.

***[gastronomic](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/gastronomic)***
adjective   formal

(also gastronomical)

> relating to the preparation and consumption (= eating) of good food:
>   - This dish is a gastronomic delight.

(Cambridge Dictiinary)

[Google books](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=gastronomic%2Cgastronomical&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgastronomic%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgastronomical%3B%2Cc0): *gastronomic vs gastronomical*

From: ***[Cycling in France](https://books.google.it/books?id=Tlz6GWaGKwMC&pg=PA82&dq=%22gastronomical%20capital%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwje6Mqt-N_pAhULXpoKHe5DBdoQ6AEIMzAC#v=onepage&q=%22gastronomical%20capital%22&f=false)***
By Carole Saint-Laurent

> Back in Lyon, which is the gastronomical capital of France, a unique culinary experience awaits you.

From: [The Rough Guide to Argentina](https://books.google.it/books?id=uax8dwX9gIwC&pg=PA131&dq=%22gastronomic%20capital%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjOpMmG-d_pAhXa4KYKHeljDVkQ6AEIMzAC#v=onepage&q=%22gastronomic%20capital%22&f=false)
By Danny Aeberhard, Andrew Benson, Rough Guides, Lucy Phillips

> Buenos Aires is arguably Latin America's gastronomic capital.